# responsive image resizing issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-animations

I'm making attempts to build a responsive site however i'm am struggling with the resizing on the two background images i applied to my site. when i view on a mobile device the header looks squashed, i presume this is become a i applied a fixed height to the header. I have tried using the property height:auto, However still no joy.
can someone point out what i'm doing wrong?

```
#header{
background: url(images/page_header_1024px.png) no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
max-width:1024px;
min-height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;}
```

[click here](http://thisiswired.com/responsive/)

Comment: what is the link to your site? But it would be easier to create a seperate thumbnail for the header for mobile devices. and overwrite in your css the background. for small devices you best keep images as small as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Write like this :

```
    html, body{
     height:100%;
    }
#header{
 min-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: that has solved the problem viewing the site landscape, however, when i view the site portrait the header looks squashed...

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're not using a standard  tag? Then the browser will natively resize it - try resizing this page (just your image in it's own window):
http://thisiswired.com/responsive/css/images/page_header_1024px.png

Is that the effect you want?

Comment: yes Luke. Cheers mate, i solved this issue a while back. Thanks for the response though.